# Node.js client app crashes during http request

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm new to node.js; I am reading a book and following it word for word. I have recently run into a problem and I do not know how to solve it. The book asks me to create a client app, I have the code which matches the book's exactly but doesn't run. Below is the code:

fiboclient.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var util = require('util');
[
    "/fibonacci/30", "/fibonacci/20", "/fibonacci/10",
    "/fibonacci/9", "/fibonacci/8", "/fibonacci/7",
    "/fibonacci/6", "/fibonacci/5", "/fibonacci/4",
    "/fibonacci/3", "/fibonacci/2", "/fibonacci/1"
].forEach(path => {
        util.log('requesting ' + path);
        var req = http.request({
                host: "localhost",
                port: 3002,
                path: path,
                method: 'GET'
         }, res => {
                 res.on('data', chunk => {
                         util.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
                 });
         });
         req.end();
});
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "fibonacci",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "DEBUG=fibonacci:* node ./bin/www",
    "server": "SERVERPORT=3002 node ./fiboserver",
    "client": "node ./fiboclient"
   },
   "dependencies": {
     "body-parser": "~1.17.1",
     "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
     "debug": "~2.6.3",
     "ejs": "~2.5.6",
     "express": "~4.15.2",
     "morgan": "~1.8.1",
     "serve-favicon": "~2.4.2"
   }
}
```

output:

```
> fibonacci@0.0.0 client 
/home/zschiff/Dropbox/Personal/Node/ch04/fibonacci
> node ./fiboclient

29 May 11:37:56 - requesting /fibonacci/30
29 May 11:37:56 - requesting /fibonacci/20
29 May 11:37:56 - requesting /fibonacci/10
29 May 11:37:56 - requesting /fibonacci/9
29 May 11:37:56 - requesting /fibonacci/8
29 May 11:37:56 - requesting /fibonacci/7
29 May 11:37:56 - requesting /fibonacci/6
29 May 11:37:56 - requesting /fibonacci/5
29 May 11:37:56 - requesting /fibonacci/4
29 May 11:37:56 - requesting /fibonacci/3
29 May 11:37:56 - requesting /fibonacci/2
29 May 11:37:56 - requesting /fibonacci/1
events.js:163
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3002
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1050:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1073:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1097:14)

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-78-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "client"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! fibonacci@0.0.0 client: `node ./fiboclient`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the fibonacci@0.0.0 client script 'node 
./fiboclient'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm 
installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the fibonacci 
package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./fiboclient
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this 
project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs fibonacci
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls fibonacci
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/zschiff/Dropbox/Personal/Node/ch04/fibonacci/npm-
debug.log
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Without knowing how your Server Side code looks this is very hard to solve..

Comment: `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED`, means the client could not connect to `127.0.0.1:3002`. make sure your server is running there.

Comment: `fiboClient` is doing a request to 127.0.0.1:3002, when you run `node client`. It appears there is no server running. Have you run `node server` on a different console window? It is hard to tell without seeing the entire code, but it appears there is just no server there.

Comment: Thanks all that was indeed the problem!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The client app (fiboclient.js) is attempting to make requests to localhost (IP 127.0.0.1), port 3002. The error "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3002" suggests that you don't have a server listening to localhost port 3002. Check that fiboserver.js is running and listening to that port.

Answer (score 0):

i was stuck in same tutorial also same problem , i found the solution in  (https://stackoverflow.com/users/714143/tedmeftah) replay , he said must run server then the client.
1 - in /fibonacci> npm run server.
2 - in /fibonacci> npm run client.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cac00.jpg)

Comment: It looks like the first link you published is broken.